# Redirect after user creation via form

Tags: 8, forms

What would be the proper hook to redirect after the user registration form is submitted and is in valid state?

I'm trying to automatically create a certain content-type node when a user registers and I want to redirect the user to that node's edit form *after* the user creation form is submitted **and** validated.

I was thinking of doing this in a `mymodule_user_form_submit` hook, but not sure if **a)** this hook exists and **b)** the validation in place for user registration will still work as intended.

Can anyone share some pointers?

**EDIT:**

Would the `mymodule_user_insert` hook run after the validation and submission of the form? Can I redirect from there? AFAIK, I won't have a `form_state` variable to act on, right?

**EDIT2:**

While researching for a solution, I noticed I have another (probably bigger) problem: the content-type node I need to create must hold a reference to the user's ID, so I'm getting in a chicken-or-egg situation.

I actually need to create said node **after** the user is created (otherwise I'll have no user_id), but I need to redirect to the node's edit form after user creation, which means I can't redirect with `$form_state`.

I think I got everything right, but I would love to be wrong. :D

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a custom user registration form `my_module_user_register_form`, then you can define one or more submit functions for it

```
function my_module_user_register_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'my_module_user_register_form_submit';
    // and now add a second submit function if you like
    $form['#submit'][] = 'my_module_user_register_form_another_submit';
}
```

and then place the appropriate redirect at the end of the last submit function.

```
function my_module_user_register_form_another_submit($form, &$form_state) {
   // do other stuff here 
   $form_state->setRedirect('node/123/edit');
}
```

Comment: `drupal_goto` does not exist in D8

Comment: Never send a response yourself, especially not in the middle of a form submission; that's a sure fire way to break something. Use `$form_state->setRedirect()`. Also small thing, the method names in your examples don't match

Comment: @Monkeybrain thanks for the updated replies. I just noted a bigger issue, though, and posted it in my question above. Any more ideas?

Comment: Yes - define multiple submit functions, the first one does the user creation, the second one does the node creation and the redirect to the node form.You could pass any necessary data between the submit functions in a $_SESSION variable.

Comment: Sounds legit... Thanks! Can you elaborate or share an example of "multiple submit functions"?

Comment: Do you mean having an "intermediate" function to which the submit redirects (the first one) and then use that intermediate function to redirect to the node edit form? How would I be sure that intermediate function gets called only after user creation (and DB operations)?

Comment: No, just add a second submit function in your login form. Editing the example now.